# Symfony 2.4 - Repeated form field - When values do not match, how to map violation to the second field?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a repeated form field (Symfony 2.4) and I'd like to map *only* the "values not matching" error to the second field (because it feels more natural in my opinion).

I tried adding this option to the form field:

`'error_mapping'   => array('.' => 'second_field_name')`

But then all the violations (even the ones related to constraints applied to the first field) get mapped to the second field.
I tried to dig into the source code but I couldn't find a property path other than `.` to catch the "values not matching" error.

Has anyone attempted something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read, I am under the impression that what you really want to do is display all the *repeated* field errors at the bottom of both fields. All errors related to one or the other contained field, should be displayed at the bottom of their respective sub-field.

What I want to make clear here is that all errors related to a single sub-field should appear only under that sub-field where the error is made ; an error related to *both* fields ("values not matching" IS such an error) should be related to the *repeated* field itself.

Thus, you don't really need to modify anything in the PHP code. You should remove your *error_mapping* propriety and let it resolve to default.

What you want to do is modify the template of the *repeated* field. For that, you might have to create a form theme for your application. If you're not acquainted to that concept, I suggest you throw an eye to [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#index-21) about this.

After that is done, you need to modify the *repeated_row* block. Form theming uses inheritance, thus the default block for the repeated field renders as such:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form_row">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

What you need to do is add this in your form theme template:

```
{% block repeated_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form_row">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock repeated_row %}
```

With this, instead of being displayed before the field, the errors related to *repeated* will be displayed after it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not only a matter of where to display errors, since I also use the information about which fields are errored to add a class for CSS element styling. Of course I could workaround that as well (similarly to what you suggested) but I was just hoping there was a clean an proper way to accomplish that without having to write view-based logic. I'll keep researching for a while and eventually mark your answer as accepted if I don't find a better way to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, styling with CSS is indeed view-based logic, isnt'it? That use of information you suggest could also be done in the form theme, and the MVC structure of Symfony should entice you to do so. That is how I would do, since I prefer to separate such logic as much as possible from PHP.

Granted, using form themes in Symfony is neither easy nor prefectly documented. But once you got the catch, it strikes you as the better way for such things.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **second** instead second_field_name

```
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', [
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'user.password_repeat.not_match',
            'error_mapping' => [
                '.' => 'second'
            ]
        ])
```

So i hope it will be helpful because google search results for this task still lead to this question without proper answer